# How to manage lots of incoming packets

Tags: java, sockets, client, packet, server

I have a socketserver set up with a remote client, and it is functional.  Upon opening the client and logging in, I noticed that **sometimes**, there is an error that seems to be due to the client reading an int when it shouldn't be.

Upon logging on, the server sends a series of messages/packets to the client, and these are anything from string messages to information used to load variables on the client's side.

Occasionally, while logging in, an error gets thrown showing that the client has read a packet of size 0 or a very large size.  Upon converting the large-sized number into ascii I once found that it was a bit of a string "sk." (I located this string in my code so it's not entirely random).

Looking at my code, I'm not sure why this is happening.  Is it possible that the client is reading an int at the wrong time? If so, how can I fix this?

```
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        connection = new Socket(address, port);
        in = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        String process;
        System.out.println("Connecting to server on "+ host + " port " + port +" at " + timestamp);
        process = "Connection: "+host + ","+port+","+timestamp + ". Version: "+version;
        write(0, process);
        out.flush();
        while (true) {
            int len = in.readInt();
            if (len < 2 || len > 2000) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Packet, length: "+len+".");
            }
            byte[] data = new byte[len];
            in.readFully(data);
            for (Byte b : data) {
                System.out.printf("0x%02X ",b);
            }
            try {
                reader.handlePackets(data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //connection.close();
                //System.exit(0);
                //System.out.println("Exiting");
            }
        }


//Here is code for my write function (Server sided):
public static void write(Client c, Packet pkt) {
    for (Client client : clients) {
        if (c.equals(client)) {
            try {
                out.writeInt(pkt.size());
                out.write(pkt.getBytes());
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So looking at the write function, I don't really see how it could be confusing the client and making it read for the size of the packet twice for one packet (at least that's what I think is happening).

If you need more information please ask me.

Comment: Show us your Packet class, please.

Comment: I have made it available here.  http://pastebin.com/dx7bYNPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client side code looks fine, and the server side code looks fine too.

The most likely issue is that this is some kind of issue with multi-threading and (improper) synchronization.  For example, maybe two server-side threads are trying to write a packet to the same client at the same time.

It is also possible that your `Packet` class has inconsistent implementations of `size()` and `getBytes()` ... or that one thread is modifying a `Packet` objects while a second one is sending it.

Comment: What can cause improper synchronization? Also, to my knowledge, each time the server is writing the packet, it's a new packet, so it shouldn't be modifying another one (I don't think).  I'm thinking there's an error related to size, but I haven't found it yet.  If that were the case, shouldn't it have this problem at every login, considering the same packets are sent each time? Instead it only happens maybe 40-60% of the time.

Comment: *"What can cause improper synchronization?"* - Incorrect code.  *"Instead it only happens maybe 40-60% of the time."*.  That is inconsistent with a problem with your application's synchronization.

Comment: Could you say more? I have printed the packet size before and after it is sent/received and the size doesn't seem to get changed.  However, the problem persists and occasionally I still receive a packet of size 0 (at login).

Comment: I could write **a whole book** on this.  But that would be redundant since other people have already done this.  I suggest that you read the Oracle Java tutorial sections on writing concurrent / multi-threaded programs, paying particular attention to the parts where it talks about synchronization and thread-safety.

Comment: Ooops ... it is **consistent** with the a synchronization problem.  Typo.

Comment: I have added synchronization to the packet writing function and while it does make everything much slower, I haven't had any issues since.  The speed should pick up when I host with a better server but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Rahul Check out "Java Concurrency in Practice". It's the ultimate reference for writing thread-safe code.